# elasticsearch abortion in docker for MacOS

Tags: docker, elasticsearch

I'm running ealsticsearch 7.0.0 in docker. But the elasticsearch container always terminates just after I start it.
I've configured docker as what [official reference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.4/docker.html) said.
`$ screen ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/vms/0/tty`
`sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144`
And an error is still logged out:

```
[1] bootstrap checks failed
[1]: the default discovery settings are unsuitable for production use; at least one of [discovery.seed_hosts, discovery.seed_providers, cluster.initial_master_nodes] must be configured
```

So where can I confirm that the **vm.max_map_count** setting is configured correctly? Or maybe because of other reasons?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you share your docker command to start the ES7.0?

Comment: docker run -d -p 9200:9200 elasticsearch:7.0.0

Comment: If you only want a single node cluster try running with `docker run -d -p 9200:9200 -e "discovery.type=single-node" elasticsearch:7.0.0`, without the discovery.type setting it will think you're trying to run in clustered mode so enforce all of the production ready checks - see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.0/docker.html#docker-cli-run-prod-mode